# Facebook Graph API: How to check if an object is a user and not another type of object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Of course you can use `http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}` to get a JSON response for that object. However, for my application I want to determine if the object returned is a *user* and not a page, group, or any other object. Or in other words, I want to query only users.

Is this possible?

I've looked through the Graph API docs, but I can't find a way to ask/query for only users.

Comment: Actually, I may just end up using FQL: "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = {user_id}"

Comment: Can object be a user? From where are you getting these objects?

Comment: @SahilMittal, yes. Well, technically, a user is an object. It looks like Facebook assigns a unique object_id to pretty much everything, including users, schools, pictures, etc. The user `object_id` is also known as the `user_id` or `profileid`. You can usually view the object_ids with the source code for a given profile page. (e.g., look for the `page_id` in the source for https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by adding the

```
metadata=1
```

parameter in the GET request URL like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}&metadata=1
```

The response will include a `type` field, which contains the object type of the object you requested

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I can't find the `metadata` query string variable in the API docs. Where did you learn about this?

Comment: Found it :) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#introspection